# I would like to make my menu effects disappear

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am new in web development. I am using the following Wordpress theme: http://test.dominikos.com/

I'd like to disable the top menu effects and make it look like simple white boxes with links.
Obviously there is a JavaScript code that needs to be disabled which I can't find.

Is there a way to locate the file via Firebug?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to purchase before making changes

Hi, you can't edit the free templates on WordPress. You first need to purchase the theme and then look for the JS which is causing this.

#### View the source code to view the file

However, You can still view the source code, just go to the link that you're on. And right-click and select View Source Code or try the keyboard shortcut of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>. You'll see the source code of the website.

#### Go and buy it and then edit it

But remember that you can't remove or edit the files and layout of the free templates.

Go and buy it, then you'll be able to edit its view! Otherwise, you might need to create your own template by using this scratch of source code. Then you'll be able to create the theme of your own choice.